# Thread and ScopedThread functions in mongo shell

Tags: multithreading, mongodb

I noticed those functions in [tests](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/365cca0c47566d192ca847f0b077cedef4b3430e/jstests/libs/parallelTester.js).
Is there any documentation about it?

How to work with threads through mongo shell?
Can I share cursor in threads?
Do I need to lock variables if I share them in threads?

Here is copy-paste for github:

```
Thread = function(){
this.init.apply( this, arguments );
}
_threadInject( Thread.prototype );

ScopedThread = function() {
this.init.apply( this, arguments );
}
ScopedThread.prototype = new Thread( function() {} );
_scopedThreadInject( ScopedThread.prototype );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a [response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/PzCiPJpjWEE/5hgi5EntPpoJ) from **Will Berkeley** (MongoDB Staff)

> That code is part of the jstests for MongoDB. It's undocumented
>   internal testing code that could change whenever and it's not intended
>   to be something people use in the shell for multithreading. If you
>   want to multithread access to the database, use an official driver in
>   a language with multithreading support.